# DSpace - XMLUI Discovery - Sorting items with a combination of metadata

Tags: metadata, dspace

I would need to sort the items displayed on the XMLUI discovery page using a combination of metadata, because the type of ordering required (specifically for size) uses a different metadata for media type of reference (see images, audio, video ...) .

Wanting to act, as per documentation, on the file "discovery.xml" but specifying a bean of this type:

```
<bean id="sortSize" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoverySortFieldConfiguration">
   <property name="metadataFields"/>
      <list>
         <value>METADATA_NAME_1</value>
         <value>METADATA_NAME_2</value>
         ...
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Indexing is not successful.
This is because it is only possible to indicate a sort bean of this type:

```
<bean id="sortSize" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoverySortFieldConfiguration">
   <property name="metadataField" value="SINGLE_METADATA_NAME"/>
</bean>
```

Is it possible to create a type of combined ordering like the one described? If so, how could I operate?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting via a list of metadataFields currently isn't possible in DSpace's Discovery module.

`DiscoverySortFieldConfiguration` only supports a single `metadataField` as noted in the documentation at: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Discovery#Discovery-Sortoptioncustomizationforsearchresults

You can also see that the code itself only supports one field: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/discovery/configuration/DiscoverySortFieldConfiguration.java#L17

Comment: Thanks Tim for your response. At this point, I would ask you if there is a possibility to customize this behaviour.

Comment: @EustachioMaselli : All code in DSpace is open source, so it could be customized. However, the existing code in Discovery has a lot of areas where the assumption is that sort is only on a single field. So, you'd literally need to look at everywhere `DiscoverySortFieldConfiguration` is used, and ensure it can be updated to allow for multiple sort fields.

Answer (score 1):

it's easy. You should try with the order by clause of Dspace. What version are you using?

Comment: Hi John, the version we are using is 4.1

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Just a question Ystacchio, do you use MVC in your project?

Comment: @JohnAndrewP.Cursor: This answer is incorrect when it comes to the DSpace Discovery module.  It sounds like you are talking more about sorting in *database queries* (which can be achieved by customizing SQL "order by" clauses).  The DSpace Discovery module doesn't use the database, but instead queries against a Solr backend.  So SQL "order by" clauses will not help in that module. (However, if the original question was about sorting DSpace database queries, then this answer would be correct.)